# iphone sdk how to catch a long press after 1 second?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to catch a Long Press event. The problem is I can only respond to it after user release his finger.

How do I implement a function that will respond after user hold for x seconds?

Answer (score 3):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer works for this, check your code again and set duration for long press as -

```
[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:<#(CFTimeInterval)#>];
```

Comment: so I'll set minimum press duration and respond immediately when the gesture is registered ?

Comment: setMinimumPressDuration to that value in which time you want to respond it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a gesture recognizer, use the UIView instance methods touchesBegan:withEvent:, touchesMoved:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent:.  While they're not as convenient as using a gesture recognizer, you have complete control of the touch interpretation.

Note that if you every try to use these to interpret multitouch gestures, the touch screen is "bouncy", in that the reported number of touches will vary during the touch event processing.  My app interprets pinches, which are reported to me as a random sequence of one and two finger touches.  I managed to debounce it, but getting the code right was a real PITA.

Comment: can you be more specific how I can check the touch duration, in which method ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Instantiate an NSDate in touchesBegan:withEvent: :

Comment: `NSDate *begin = [NSDate date];`

Comment: Instantantiate another date in touchesMoved:withEvent: then compare it to the first: `NSTimeInterval interval = [movedDate timeIntervalSinceDate: begin];`

Comment: Actually the date you instantiate in touchesBegan:withEvent: needs to be a member variable, so it will still exist in touchesMoved.

Comment: both touchesMoved and touchesBegan will need to check that the number of touches is equal to one.